# How to replace integer entry of a DataFrame to a string based on a range

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of numbers that I would like to change to a string based on if the number is within a given range.

Given df (these are int, not strings):

```
tempList
10
98
33
65
254
```

Ranges:

```
<40 = "Cold Temp"
41-80 = "Good Temp"
>81 = "Hot Temp"
```

Desired Output:

```
tempList
Cold Temp
Hot Temp
Cold Temp
Good Temp
Hot Temp
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think in the last condition you meant `>80`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['tempList'].apply(lambda x: "Cold Temp" if x < 40 else ("Good Temp" if x < 81 else "Hot Temp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) here.

```
df['Ranges'] = pd.cut(x=df['tempList'],
                      bins=[0,40,80,np.inf], 
                      labels=['Cold Temp', 'Good Temp', 'Hot Temp'])
print(df)
```

```
   tempList     Ranges
0        10  Cold Temp
1        98   Hot Temp
2        33  Cold Temp
3        65  Good Temp
4       254   Hot Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['temperature'])
df['temperature'] = [10,98,33,65,254]
    
df['temperature'] = np.where(df['temperature']<40, 'cold', np.where(df['temperature']<80, 'good', 'hot'))
    
print(df)
```